# How to solve Google oauth with jenkins logging error

Tags: jenkins, oauth, google-oauth

I have configured jenkins to work with google oauth using the google-login plugin. I've followed the setup and it is taking me to the google login page. But when it is redirected to the securityRealm/finishLogin endpoint, it is giving me an error:
[Jenkins error after redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39B1K.png)

I see the following timeout log in the jenkins logs:

```
2024-02-13 09:31:46.550+0000 [id=77]    WARNING h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID afe6c48b-2369-4053-9e14-21ef1e284455
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:551)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:304)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenResponse.execute(IdTokenResponse.java:115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm$2.onSuccess(GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.java:204)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.OAuthSession.doFinishLogin(OAuthSession.java:112)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.java:305)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:698)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:248)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:163)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:44)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.provideRequestDuring(ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.java:106)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.doFilter(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:44)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at jenkins.util.HttpServletFilter$1.doFilter(HttpServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.ErrorAttributeFilter.doFilter(ErrorAttributeFilter.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

Following is my configuration in google:
[Google developer console config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAuab.png)

Following is my configuration in jenkins:
[Jenkins security congig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk8P2.png)

I have tried fresh installation of jenkins, I have tired using jenkins without any other plugin so that there is no clash